# How to create an instance of an inherited class in unittest Python so that I can register the instance of that class in simpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, xml-rpc

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from sikuli.Sikuli import *

import os
import unittest
import this
import xmlrpclib
import SimpleXMLRPCServer, SocketServer, threading

class SimpleThreadedXMLRPCServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    pass

class ABC(object):
    def A(self):
      ...........
    def B(self):
      ...........
    def C(self):
      ...........     


class XYZ(unittest.TestCase,ABC):
    def setUp(self):
         print "Inside setup"
         pass      
    def tearDown(self):
         print "Inside tearDown" 
         pass
    def test_1(self):
        self.A()
        self.B()
        self.C()


    def D(self):    
        print "Inside D"
        return True    


suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(XYZ)

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.server = SimpleThreadedXMLRPCServer(("x.x.x.1", 8000))
        #self.server.register_instance() #How to Register an instance of XYZ here.
    def run(self):
        self.server.serve_forever()

server = ServerThread()
server.start()
```

So my question is that how to Register an instance of `XYZ` here. In the commented line above so that it can be called from the XMLRPC client like:

```
client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://x.x.x.2:8000")
handraise = client.D() #Or any other possible way
```

I know it works with `register_function(D)` but I want the whole class `XYZ` to be exposed using `register_instance()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically this should work:

```
self.server.register_instance(XYZ())    # but it throwed some runTest Error for me
```

Anyways, passing the method name explicitly as an arg in the Classname inside register_instance like:

```
self.server.register_instance(XYZ("D"))
```

worked as expected for me.
And from the xmlrpc client, call the D() like:

```
handraise = client.D()
```